# How to bind authenticated user to parameter in controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I cant retrieve authenticated webmaster in controller. As you can see below, i authenticate user in constructor via `$this->middleware`:

```
class DomainController 
.....
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:webmasters');
    }
    public function requestNewName(Request $request, Webmaster $webmaster, DomainRepositoryInterface $domainRepository): array
    {
        // $webmaster->id === null here
        /** @var Webmaster $webmaster */
        $webmaster = Auth::user(); // $webmaster->id === 1, all OK
        $domainRepository->requestChangeName($webmaster, $request->input('newName', ''));
        return ['result' => true];
    }
....
```

I think i need to bind it somewhere, but i dont understand where or how?

P. S.

Now i have in AuthServiceProvider:

```
    foreach ([Webmaster::class, Admin::class] as $class) {
        $this->app->bind($class, static function($app) use ($class) {
            $authenticated = Auth::user();
            /** @noinspection GetClassUsageInspection */
            return $authenticated && get_class($authenticated) === $class ? $authenticated : null;
        });
    }
}
```

And call this function in boot method. I bet that laravel has something for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the webmaster to be injected into your method by laravel's dependency injection.

The way you would do this is through the Service Container, which is the guy who handles the injections. When you as for a Webmaster $webmaster, it looks for a binding with that type, since you haven't done an explicit bind, it tries to give you an instance anyways, but that's a generic one.

All you gotta do is add this code in your service provider:

```
$this->app->bind('App\Webmaster', function ($app) {
   return Auth::user();
});
```

Now laravel knows how you want Webmaster to be injected into the function.

Comment: But where is the best place to do so? And how to prevent giving me generic model?

Comment: You put this code on your AppServiceProvider and it will always give you the authenticated Webmaster, if there is none, I don't know if it will give you null or an exception

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation. Your code looks ok to me. But one thing comes to mind.

Since `$webmaster->id` gives you null means that the `Webmaster` class is imported properly in the `DomainController`. But maybe you haven't imported the `Webmaster` class properly in the `AuthServiceProvider`. Also maybe `dd(get_class($webmaster));` will help. What does `Auth::user()` return in your app, anyway?

Comment: `$webmaster->id` should give me id (1,2,3,....). With code in the end of my question everything works fine.

Comment: I know what you mean. As I said, check if `Webmaster` class is imported properly. And for debugging purpose do `dd(get_class($webmaster));` in the `requestNewName` action.

Comment: With code in the end it gives me correct entity. Without it gives me blank entity. `Webmaster` class in both cases